# Jinja2 Extension Tag within another Tag

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm tring to do something like this

```
{% mytag country "italy" year "2014" %}
    workday
{% holyday %}
    not workday
{% endmytag %}
```

But the holyday tag is optional. 
This must work too:

```
{% mytag country "italy" year "2014" %}
    workday
{% endmytag %}
```

I wrote the code

```
class MytagExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['mytag'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(TranslateExtension, self).__init__(environment)

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = parser.stream.next().lineno

        if parser.stream.skip_if('name:country'):
            country= parser.parse_primary()
        else:
            country= nodes.Const(None)
        if parser.stream.skip_if('name:year'):
            year = parser.parse_primary()
        else:
            year = nodes.Const(None)

        args = [country, year]

        # body1 = parser.parse_statements(['name:holyday']) # not working :)

        body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endmytag'], drop_needle=True)
        return nodes.CallBlock(self.call_method('_helper', args),
                           [], [], body).set_lineno(lineno)

    def _helper(self, country, year, caller):
        etc ....
```

Is similar to a `if else endif`, but i didn't find the source code of the `if` tag (if it exists as Extension)

How can i do this?
Obviously in my `_helper` I need both the first and second branch because is there that I choose which one to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here is an answer, it's not perfect and probably not the best, but it's something.

```
    ...
    body = parser.parse_statements(
               ['name:endmytag', 'name:holyday'], 
               drop_needle=True
           )
    if not parser.stream.current.test('block_end'):
        body.extend ( parser.parse_statements(['name:endmytag'], drop_needle=True) )

    args = [
         country, 
         year, 
         nodes.Const([y.data for x in body for y in x.nodes]), #I don't like this line a lot :)
           ]
    return nodes.CallBlock(self.call_method('_helper', args),
                           [], [], body).set_lineno(lineno)
    ...
```

In this way in the `_helper` you will receive the third parameter (a list) and choose if return the first or the second element of this list.